# vector point precision Error

Tags: c#, directx

Our application contains .Net FrameWork3.5 and DirectX For Making 2d drawing.
we are stuck with precision problem.Please give solution to solve the precision problem.

we are using vector3f(vector points) to store the values. while we store the result of point in vector3f only 2 precision value is matched.But we need 5 precision value.

Here i have mentioned my code below..

//Function To find ARC Parameters from Bulge value

polylineVertStart=6919.602,18951.51,0   polylineVertEnd=6916.602,18951.51,0

Arc StartPoint=6919.602,18951.5177,0    Endpoint=6916.602,18951.51,0

```
   public static Arc BulgeToArc(PolylineVertex3d polylineVertStart, PolylineVertex3d polylineVertEnd)
    {
        PolylineVertex3d polylineVertex3d = polylineVertEnd;
        PolylineVertex3d polylineVertex3d1 = polylineVertStart; //get previous point

        double x1 = polylineVertex3d1.Position.X;   //Assign start and end points
        double y1 = polylineVertex3d1.Position.Y;
        double x2 = polylineVertex3d.Position.X;
        double y2 = polylineVertex3d.Position.Y;           

        if (y1 == y2)
        {
            y2 += (y1 * 0.0000001);
        }
        if (x1 == x2)
        {
            x2 += (x1 * 0.0000001);
        }

        double bulge = polylineVertex3d1.Bulge;
        double incAngle = 4 * System.Math.Atan(System.Math.Abs(bulge));     //included Angle
        double chord = System.Math.Sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)); //Chord length
        double r = 0.5 * chord / System.Math.Cos(0.5 * incAngle - 0.5 * System.Math.PI); //Calculate radius
        double Radius = r;

        double dx = x2 - x1;
        double dy = y2 - y1;

        double slope = dy / dx;     //slope of two points
        double slopeAng = System.Math.Atan(slope);

        if (System.Math.Sign(dy) == -1 && System.Math.Sign(dx) == -1)
        {
            slopeAng = System.Math.PI + slopeAng;
        }
        else if (System.Math.Sign(dy) == -1 && System.Math.Sign(dx) == 1)
        {
            slopeAng = 2 * System.Math.PI + slopeAng;
        }
        else if (System.Math.Sign(dy) == 1 && System.Math.Sign(dx) == -1)
        {
            slopeAng = System.Math.PI + slopeAng;
        }

        double d1 = System.Math.Sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));

        double d2 = d1 / 2;
        double startAng = System.Math.Acos(d2 / r);     //calculate start angle
        double sAngle;


        if (System.Math.Abs(bulge) < 1) //get actual start angle based on bulge direction
        {
            if (System.Math.Sign(bulge) != -1)
            {
                sAngle = slopeAng + startAng;
            }
            else
            {
                sAngle = slopeAng - startAng;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (System.Math.Sign(bulge) != -1)
            {
                sAngle = slopeAng - startAng;
            }
            else
            {
                sAngle = slopeAng + startAng;
            }
        }

        double cx = x1 + r * System.Math.Cos(sAngle);
        double cy = y1 + r * System.Math.Sin(sAngle);
        Vector3F Center = new Vector3F((float)cx, (float)cy, 0f);  //calculate center point


        double dx1 = x1 - cx;
        double dx2 = x2 - cx;
        double dy1 = y1 - cy;
        double dy2 = y2 - cy;

        double sAng = System.Math.Atan(dy1 / dx1);
        double eAng = System.Math.Atan(dy2 / dx2);


        if (System.Math.Sign(dy1) == -1 && System.Math.Sign(dx1) == -1)
        {
            sAng = System.Math.PI + sAng;
        }
        else if (System.Math.Sign(dy1) == -1 && System.Math.Sign(dx1) != -1)
        {
            sAng = 2 * System.Math.PI + sAng;
        }
        else if (System.Math.Sign(dx1) == -1)
        {
            sAng = System.Math.PI + sAng;
        }

        if (System.Math.Sign(dy2) == -1 && System.Math.Sign(dx2) == -1)
        {
            eAng = System.Math.PI + eAng;
        }
        else if (System.Math.Sign(dy2) == -1 && System.Math.Sign(dx2) != -1)
        {
            eAng = 2 * System.Math.PI + eAng;
        }
        else if (System.Math.Sign(dx2) == -1)
        {
            eAng = System.Math.PI + eAng;
        }

        double StartAngle;
        double EndAngle;

        if (System.Math.Sign(bulge) != -1)  //finalise start angle and end angle
        {
            StartAngle = sAng;
            EndAngle = eAng;
        }
        else
        {
            StartAngle = eAng;
            EndAngle = sAng;
        }


        Direction dir;
        if (polylineVertStart.Bulge != 0)
            dir = polylineVertStart.Bulge < 0 ? Direction.ClockWise : Direction.CounterClockWise;
        else
            dir = polylineVertEnd.Bulge < 0 ? Direction.ClockWise : Direction.CounterClockWise;

        Arc arc = dir == Direction.ClockWise ? new Arc(Center, new Vector3F(0f, 0f, 1f), Radius, EndAngle, StartAngle, dir) : new Arc(Center, new Vector3F(0f, 0f, 1f), Radius, StartAngle, EndAngle, dir);

        return arc;
    }


  //Function to find ARC from StartAngle,EndAngle,Radius 

     public RenderingEngine.Geometry GetGeomtry()
    {
        RenderingEngine.Geometry geometry = new RenderingEngine.Geometry
                                                {
                                                    EntityPrimitiveType = EntityPrimitiveType.LineStrip
                                                };
        xPoints.Clear();
        yPoints.Clear();
        zPoints.Clear();
        VertexList.Clear();
        List<CustomVertex.PositionColored> vertices = new List<CustomVertex.PositionColored>();

        if (direction == Direction.ClockWise)
        {
            #region clockwise
            double WedgeAngle = 0.0; //clock wise
            if (EndAngle != StartAngle)
            {
                if (EndAngle < StartAngle)
                {
                    WedgeAngle = (StartAngle - EndAngle) / NUMPOINTS;
                }
                else
                {
                    WedgeAngle = ((System.Math.PI * 2) - (EndAngle - StartAngle)) / NUMPOINTS;
                }
            }

            double angle = StartAngle;
            for (int i = 0; i <= NUMPOINTS; i++)
            {
                double theta = angle - (i * WedgeAngle);
                double x = center.X + (radius * SystemMath.Cos(theta));
                double y = center.Y + (radius * SystemMath.Sin(theta));
                double z = center.Z;

                CustomVertex.PositionColored positionColored = new CustomVertex.PositionColored
                                                                   {
                                                                       Position =
                                                                           new Vector3((float) x, (float) y,
                                                                                       (float) z),
                                                                       Color = Color.ToArgb()
                                                                   };
                vertices.Add(positionColored);

                xPoints.Add((float)x);
                yPoints.Add((float)y);
                zPoints.Add((float)z);
                VertexList.Add(new Vector3F((float)x, (float)y, (float)z));
            }

            double startx = Center.X + (Radius * System.Math.Cos(StartAngle));
            double starty = Center.Y + (Radius * System.Math.Sin(StartAngle));
            double startz = Center.Z;
            double endx = Center.X + (Radius * System.Math.Cos(EndAngle));
            double endy = Center.Y + (Radius * System.Math.Sin(EndAngle));
            double endz = Center.Z;
            startPoint = new Vector3F((float)startx, (float)starty, (float)startz);
            endPoint = new Vector3F((float)endx, (float)endy, (float)endz);
            #endregion clockwise
        }
        else
        {
            #region Counter ClockWise

            double WedgeAngle = 0.0;
            if (EndAngle != StartAngle)
            {
                if (EndAngle > StartAngle)
                {
                    WedgeAngle = (EndAngle - StartAngle) / NUMPOINTS;
                }
                else
                {
                    WedgeAngle = ((System.Math.PI * 2 - StartAngle) + EndAngle) / NUMPOINTS;
                }
            }
            double angle = StartAngle;
            for (int i = 0; i <= NUMPOINTS; i++)
            {
                double theta = angle + (i * WedgeAngle);
                double x = center.X + (radius * SystemMath.Cos(theta));
                double y = center.Y + (radius * SystemMath.Sin(theta));
                double z = center.Z;


                CustomVertex.PositionColored positionColored = new CustomVertex.PositionColored
                                                                   {
                                                                       Position =
                                                                           new Vector3((float) x, (float) y,
                                                                                       (float) z),
                                                                       Color = Color.ToArgb()
                                                                   };
                vertices.Add(positionColored);

                xPoints.Add((float)x);
                yPoints.Add((float)y);
                zPoints.Add((float)z);
                VertexList.Add(new Vector3F((float)x, (float)y, (float)z));
            }

            double startx = Center.X + (Radius * System.Math.Cos(StartAngle));
            double starty = Center.Y + (Radius * System.Math.Sin(StartAngle));
            double startz = Center.Z;
            double endx = Center.X + (Radius * System.Math.Cos(EndAngle));
            double endy = Center.Y + (Radius * System.Math.Sin(EndAngle));
            double endz = Center.Z;
            startPoint = new Vector3F((float)startx, (float)starty, (float)startz);
            endPoint = new Vector3F((float)endx, (float)endy, (float)endz);
            #endregion
        }
        geometry.Vertices.Add(vertices);

        return geometry;
    }


 Here arc start point and endpoint x value always come correctly but y value is some precision problem.
```

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: please post some code so we can see precision problem

Comment: Have voted to close this as there's far too much code and the problem is very specific. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html is a good place to start if you've got floating point problems. Also, learn how to use a debugger to see follow the flow of the algorithm, maybe there's an error in there or the algorithm loses precision at various points.

Comment: I support Skizz' comment. The float data type can only hold ~8 significand decimal digits.